# solaris 10 - custom jumpstart menu.lst

Tags: solaris, jumpstart

Is it possible to include the config.tar (encompasses the rules before/after scripts…) instead of on a web server served through http:// - but included no the cdrom itself.

Namely am trying to do something along the lines of:

title Solaris 
        kernel$ /boot/multiboot kernel/$ISADIR/unix install cdrom:/config/config.tar dhcp -B install_media=cdrom 
        module$ /boot/$ISADIR/x86.miniroot

Yet it seems Solaris only supports HTTP or NFS as the source for config.tar - and not the CDROM itself.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
file://jumpstart/config.tar
```

i.e. "file:" instead of "cdrom:".